# Empty Address on Docker Desktop kubernates for Ingress

Tags: docker, kubernetes, desktop, nginx-ingress

[image: k8 ingress yaml which is used to deploy ingress in docker desktop k8 but not working address is always empty any one please help me on this]

k8 ingress yaml which is used to deploy ingress in docker desktop k8 but not working address is always empty any one please help me on this

```
$ kubectl get ingress springboot-ingress
NAME                 HOSTS                  ADDRESS   PORTS   AGE
springboot-ingress   espark.com,localhost             80      12m
```

Comment: i am a beginner, let me see if i can help. Does `kubectl get pods -n kube-system` show the `nginx-ingress-controller` running?

Comment: Also you should mention the OS you are running k8s on

Comment: Also instead of wildcard `*` you should be using regex like this `/v1/api/address/?(.*)`, add `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: 'true'` to your annotations to use regex in the path

Comment: host os Mac Os Catalina 10.15.6 is os

Comment: Check if the ingress controller is assigned an ip. kubectl get svc <ingress-controller-svc> - n namespace

Answer (score 2):

working code git url
https://github.com/adarshkumarsingh83/kubernetes/tree/master/springboot-kubernetes-ingress-lb

i have used below url

```
$ kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/nginx-0.30.0/deploy/static/mandatory.yaml
$ kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/nginx-0.30.0/deploy/static/provider/cloud-generic.yaml
$ kubectl apply -f $(pwd)/kubernates/ingress.yaml
```

and change the ingress yaml one line and it worked for me

```
  
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: springboot-ingress
spec:
  rules:
    - host: espark.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /v1/api/address
            backend:
              serviceName: espark-address-service
              servicePort: 8080
          - path: /v1/api/employee
            backend:
              serviceName: espark-employee-service
              servicePort: 8080
    - host: localhost
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /v1/api/address
            backend:
              serviceName: espark-address-service
              servicePort: 8080
          - path: /v1/api/employee
            backend:
              serviceName: espark-employee-service
              servicePort: 8080
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if *endpoint* is generated for your service by `kubectl get endpoints`  and verify it has IP. If not, check the selectors and port in your *service* resource, they should match at least one running *pod*, otherwise what you see above will happen.

Comment: ```$ kubectl get endpoints
NAME         ENDPOINTS           AGE
kubernetes   192.168.65.3:6443   5d4h
```

Comment: ```$ kubectl get pods 
- No resources found in default namespace.
```